# Skydrive WelcomeScreen on Each Boot

Tags: windows-8

Every time I reboot my machine Windows 8.1 64 bit machine the "Welcome to Skyrdive" wizard shows up.  It won't stop even after completing the wizard.  Is this a bug or a virus?

Comment: Why is this question down-voted?  Seems like reasonable question.

Answer (score -1):

The software could be between startup executables? You can check this and possibly remove using the `msconfig` utility: <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and type `msconfig`.